# How to make adaptive UIImageView using Autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout

I'm a bit new to Auto layout so I've got some issues with it

I wanna to put logo of company in the top of the screen with horizontal alignment  and I need to resize it when the size of screen is getting change  please take a look to screenshots 
in other word i wanna to increase image's size when the screen get bigger and decrease  image's size when the screen get smaller

[IPhone7+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEzkH.png)

[IPhone7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFVH5.png)

[IPhoneSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3o7n.png)

[IPhone4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klAQ4.png)

so how can i achieve it ???

best regards

Comment: Can you describe the intended layout in words? For example: "the image should maintain it's aspect ratio and it's width should be half of the screen's width" or "the image should have a fixed 80 point margin on both the leading and trailing sides (left and right) and fill the space in-between those margins."

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist  yes I wanna to be as aspect ratio (width = height) but when i 've used it the image's size dosen't change

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mockup of what you want or design. You can apply Equal Width constraint with your parent view and specify the ratio in which you want. This will resize the image according to all the screen. Considering you have images of all sizes and it is a square then you can use Aspect Ratio 1:1.

If not, then what I'll do is Aspect Ratio with multiplier of original image size (eg: 133:258). Then after that only apply that Equal width constraint with parent to get that ratio. Then you can use Content Mode Aspect Fit. As we have added constraints based on the image ratio only.

Comment: First of all I don't have mockup it 's normal image i use it as logo
Second  when I 've tried  the solution  but the image’s size doesn’t change

Why should I use 133:258 values  for multiple  why this biggest values ? What the difference between  them (133:258 ) and (1:2)?